# accessing @service spring class from main executed thread

Tags: java, spring

Code sample:

@SpringBootApplication
public class Launcher {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Server Started!");
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Launcher.class)
    .headless(false).run(args);
    ctx.getBean(Launcher.class);
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Administration(ctx).setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

When the Administration class runs , will it have a valid context ? I want to pass the context inside Administration so that I can call some of the services that is provided. If this doesn't work, how can I access the services from a thread that is not in it's context ?